# What do the G, L and E avatar attributes mean?

Tags: groove-coaster

When selecting an avatar, a small descriptive blurb scrolls across the bottom of the screen. At the end of each blurb, three attributes seem to be displayed: G (integer), L (integer) and E (percentage). As far as I can tell, these aren't explained anywhere in-game.

What does each letter stand for, and what effects do these attributes have?

[image]

Comment: Gold, Life, Energy? Looking over the publisher's page, it's in Japanese and google translate isn't helping much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered the answer to this on the [Groove Coaster Facebook page](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=149545775127671).

> When selecting an Avatar, a description of that Avatar is displayed at the
>   bottom of the screen, followed by the letters G, L, and E and some numbers.
>   These letters and the values associated with them signify the special
>   attributes for that Avatar as follows:
>   G (GROOVE): This is the initial amount of GROOVE you begin a stage with.
>   L (LENGTH): This refers to the length of the Groove Gauge.
>   E (EXP): This amount modifies the amount of experience points earned when
>   playing stages.